# How do I make a bash script terminate on new line

Tags: bash, input, sh

This is for learning purposes.  I wrote a script that will simulate typing.

The usage is:

```
$ typewriter (insert some text here)
```

Then the script will echo it in a random way that looks like someone is typing.  Fine,  but the problem is, if the input includes a semicolon ( ; ) it breaks.

For instance:

```
$ typewriter hello; world
```

I imagine this is a simple fix.  I just cannot figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Displays input as if someone were typing it

RANGE=4
the_input=$*
if [ x$* = "x" ] || [ x$* = "xusage" ] || [ x$* = "xhelp" ] || [ x$* = "x--help" ];
then
        echo "Usage: typewriter <some text that you want to look like it's typed>"
        exit 1

fi
  while [ -n "$the_input" ]
  do
    number=$RANDOM
    let "number %= RANGE"
    printf "%c" "$the_input"
    sleep .$number
    the_input=${the_input#?}
  done
  printf "\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also modify your script to read from stdin:

```
the_input=`cat`
```

The cat command will assign to the_input  all the input from the user until a ^D is typed.

The advantages are that the user can type more than one line and the spacing 
within the line will be preserved.

Neat script!

Answer (score 5):

Not really: `;` signals the end of the command. You'll have a similar issue with pipes and input/output redirection (`|`, `<`, `>`), symbols that have meaning.

Your only alternative is to put the argument in quotes.

```
typewriter "some; text<>| that should be displayed"
```

Comment: Thanks, trutheality.  I must have had tunnel vision last night to not see this simple fix.  I wish I could mark both answers as the solution...